# ORA-29913 and ORA-30653 error selecting an external table

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-sql-developer

I created an external table using a .tbl file and now Im trying to select all rows from that table, using:

```
select * from users_load;
```

But Im getting this error:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-30653: reject limit reached
```

Do you know why this error is happening? This table have millions of rows, I dont know if can be because of this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the number of rows allowed to be rejected before throwing an error, or you can specify `UNLIMITED`. I guess you specified a number, but your `.tbl` file contains rows that the database can't parse appropriately based on your definition.

[image]

If you want to ignore all malformed rows, you can simply change the limit to `UNLIMITED`:

```
alter table users_load reject limit unlimited;
```

create table example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_load (
    employee_number CHAR(5)
) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_dir
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        ...
    )
    LOCATION ('foo.txt')
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED; --Use limit, not limited
```